# What is 方 used for in 早く行った方が良かったでしょう?

Tags: comparative-constructions

- 早く行った方が良かったでしょう。

Here, if we take it apart we shall have:

- 早く(Adverb) 行った(Verb, Past tense) 方(?)  が(GA, Subject particle) 良かったでしょう(Verb, Past tense) 。

What is the function of 方 in this position? I've read that it can be suffix, suffix of what?

Comment: may we see some of the context for this sentence? I would like to  provide a more accurate translation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A方{ほう}がB means "more B if A" or "B-er if A":

> 早く行った**方が良かった**でしょう。
> It *would have been better* [more good] if (we/you/I etc) had gone early, would it not?

The 方 here indicates a direction/side when comparing 2 or more things, in this case implying going early would have been better than going later.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Cypher's explanation, and with the definition of 方 as a noun.

I would like to propose an alternative translation of the sentence:

> 早く行った方が良かったでしょう。
>
> "The sooner you went, the better."
>
> "The sooner you had gone, the better."
>
> "It probably would have been better if you had gone sooner."